# what is equivalent to allowlayoutchange="false" allowpersonalization="false" allowcustomization="false"><ZoneTemplate> in object model

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

what is equivalent to allowlayoutchange="false" allowpersonalization="false" allowcustomization="false"> in object model

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpartzone_members.aspx) has the properties

- AllowCustomization
- AllowLayoutChange
- AllowPersonalization

Comment: ListViewWebPart lvwp = new ListViewWebPart(); It does not like if I use lvwp.Zone.AllowLayoutChange = false; or I dont even see allowcustomization or allow personalization. How to use them.

Comment: ListViewWebPart is a web part - not a zone. A zone *contains* web parts. You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Gien I am looking in the wrong place. Where and How is done then? My web part page called "Customer.aspx" where I am inserting 3 listview webparts. I am guessing it's has to be at the "web part page" level not web part.

Comment: Look at your question, you asked a specific thing and you've got a specific answer. Now you're asking something else (I can't tell exactly what your asking). If you can't ask the right question how do you get expect to get the right answer?